# How to measure context switching overhead on windows?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to check how much cpu time context switching is taking on windows, or better yet, an .net process?

Comment: Do you mean how much time the actual context switches are taking? Or do you mean how much CPU usage wouldn't have happened if not for a context switch? These are two very different things because a significant fraction of the cost of a context switch comes after the context switch in the form of caches that don't hold useful data.

Comment: How much time of the processor is crunching context switches in a given time. like kernel time, but only accounting context switching.

Answer (score 6):

Performance Monitor can be used to see the % processor time and # of context switches. The context switch counts are available in either:

- System\Context Switches/sec counter reports system wide context switches.
- Thread(_Total)\Context Switches/sec counter reports the total number
  of context switches generated per second by all threads

Context switch overhead is low but if you see a much higher number at the same time as % processor time spikes then you can start troubleshooting what is occurring at that time. Other counters can help with narrowing down what the problem might be - for example Processor Queue Length.

Ref: TechNet [Monitoring Context Switches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

As well from another article on [Context Switches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938613.aspx):

> You can determine whether context switching is excessive by comparing
>   it with the value of Processor\% Privileged Time. If this counter is
>   at 40 percent or more and the context-switching rate is high, then you
>   can investigate the cause for high rates of context switches.